# React Styleguidist and SASS

Tags: reactjs, sass, react-styleguidist

So my set up is pretty simple

**styleguide.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    components: 'src/components/**/*.js',
    require: [
        path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss')
    ]
};
```

Whenever I run npm run styleguide I get this error:

Module parse failed: Unexpected character @ You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

**bootstrap.scss** looks like this:

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
...
...
```

I understand I need to add SASS-loader but the examples I found are using different context so I cant really figure them out yet.

p.s. SASS works outside React Styleguide when I run the app itself, not styleguide.

Comment: We have an extensive guide about that: https://react-styleguidist.js.org/docs/webpack.html — is anything missing there?

Comment: I think the issue is that react-styleguidist is going to look for ./webpack.config.js in the root directory but in my case it was under config/webpack.config.dev.js (i am using create-react-app)

Comment: This is similar to webpack itself. You either follow a convention or require a file yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so the solution is to make sure that your main project can comiple SASS. But thats a different question.

I just had to add webpackConfig to

**styleguide.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    components: 'src/kitchensink/**/*.js',
    webpackConfig: require('./config/webpack.config.dev.js'),
    require: [
        path.join(__dirname, './src/sass/bootstrap.scss')
    ]
};
```